# Change defined states via Actionscript

Tags: actionscript, flex4.5

I use states in a Flex application to switch from normal to fullscreen view. These states are defined in mxml and in a specific tag:

```
<local:RSVideo 
            id="video" 
            width.normal="534" 
            height.normal="300"
            width.fullScreen="100%"
            height.fullScreen="100%"

        />
```

How can i change the width.fullscreen & height.fullscreen in the AS Sourcecode? I need the dimension of the display that are computed at runtime.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, i found the solution:

```
<local:RSVideo 
        id="video" 
        width.normal="534" 
        height.normal="300"
        width.fullScreen="{Capabilities.screenResolutionX}"
        height.fullScreen="{Capabilities.screenResolutionY}"

    />
```

Thanks for reading my question.
If you got another solution. Please, let me know.